# drupal7 expired node republishing

Tags: drupal-7

Hye
     I used node expiry module for the content expiry module. It expires my content after the time I gave it to expire.I want to repost the content after expiry after the permission of admin. I used node expiry extras module for it. it updates the content for next expiry time but without permission of admin. I want this thing by admin approval kindly guide me in this thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, i would create a new node status like "pending admin approval", and when a user publish a node, the node is actually going pending approval. Then only the admin can really publish the node.

So you create a Workflow of validation with https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow and that should achieve your goal.

Cheers